# Problem With Editing TableView Code

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have made a table containing an array editable (you can delete rows) by swiping and clicking delete.  However, I am trying to make it so you click the edit button in the navbar and the red minus sign comes up next to each cell.

I am using the code from my book but the tableView variable is not working.  I can't figure out how it is working in the book but not in my project.

I think it is because the book's class is a subclass of UITableViewController while mine is a UIViewController with a UITableViewController Object in it.  So how can I get this to work?

I have an IBOutlet for tableView in my interface file too.

Here is the relevant code:

```
#import "RoutineTableViewController.h"
#import "AlertPrompt.h"

@implementation RoutineTableViewController

@synthesize myArray;
@synthesize myData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    myData = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"] retain]; 

    if (myData == nil)
    {
        myData = [NSMutableArray array];  
    }

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
    [editButton release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)toggleEdit:(id)sender
{
    [self.tableView setEditing: !=self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.tableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with the object of UITableViewController in UIViewController class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might look like I am assuming you are a total newbie, but trust me, many people forget this (I'm not saying I'm an expert either), but you should check if your edit button is connected to the corresponding `IBOutlet` in Interface Builder.

EDIT: Forgot to ask, is your button an IBOutlet (IB element)? Or is it created programmatically? If the second is true, then you should NOT use IBActions for programmatically created objects (hence Interface Builder Action = IBAction)

Comment: also, my suggestion is that the IBAction you're using is connected to your button on IB and not programmatically

Comment: everything is done programmatically so there is nothing to connect in, right?

Comment: right, so then your method return type should not be set to `IBAction`, you should set it to `void`, like this: `- (void)toggleEdit`, note that the `id` argument is not needeed

Comment: also, take into account what drewag said

Comment: By the way, do you know how to make it so when you're in edit mode, the the button turns red?  right now it just changes text to delete, but im sure there is a way to make it red while saying delete.

Comment: I think that's due to what drewag said, you should check that, if you encounter any more problems create a new question (which is what you should have done anyway) -> and let me know when you do so! (also let me know in another comment if this solved your second question)

Comment: umm everything works fine except the nav button doesn't turn red (or maybe it was supposed to turn blue).

Comment: Ah right, so you were talking about the nav button. I don't know about that, but to the extents of my knowledge, that is only possible by subclassing the button and implementing your own behavior, check this [Core Data Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) out and look at the way they implement the editing code

Comment: specifically, you are looking for the 'The Table View Controller' section and the 'Deleting Events' section

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the editingStyle of each UITableViewCell to be UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete. This should be done when creating the cell within the table view's delegate (tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)